# LM-Sensors - Intel Arc A750 + Dell R720 + Debian 11 (Kernel 6.2.2)

Tags: linux, intel, gpu

I have a Dell R720 at home running virtualized services under KVM. I have recently added an Intel ARC A750 which I've passed through a Debian 11 VM (with a Q35 machine model), where I have Jellyfin running. The sole purpose of the card is transcoding videos.

I have compiled the new 6.2.2 kernel for the VM in order to get the card going, and it's been working wonders.

In order to see the card utilization, I've come across the "intel-gpu-tools" project, which beautifully solves the that issue with "intel_gpu_top".

**The problem**

Given that the card has it's fans facing downwards, I'm not sure if the idle speed is enough to cool it down, given it's placement (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjism.jpg)). I'm running lm-sensors version 3.6.0-7, and it reports as:

```
i915-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
in0:           0.00 V  
power1:           N/A  (max = 190.00 W)
energy1:     244.36 kJ
```

It seems that lm-sensors might've not been updated for this card, yet it still seems to be reading *something*. What is the intended method of checking the temperature of the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this topic](https://www.phoronix.com/review/intel-arc-nov), `However, the graphics card temperature monitoring isn't yet supported.`